# Dynamically check/uncheck checkbox based off of selection

Tags: angular

Basically, I just want to uncheck one checkbox if I select a certain checkbox. I would like to uncheck or check a checkbox depending on what is checked. Example. If I check "Admin", "SuperAdmin" and then later select "ProcessLevel", I want "Admin" and "SuperAdmin" to be removed from my array and "Admin" and "SuperAdmin" checkbox to be unchecked if checked. I am populating my checkbox using a "Role" array. I'm trying to use 2 way binding.

I'm using Angular 11.

Here's my html code for the checkbox control:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ member.roleId }}" id="{{ member.roleName }} 
   [disabled]="role.roleName == 'User'" [checked]="role.roleName == 'User'" 
    (change)="onRoleChange(role.roleId, role.roleName, $event)"> {{ role.roleName }}
```

Here's my .ts code:
This is the object I'm using to hold my checkbox data and the "user" object that I want to send to the server to insert the data.

```
    roles: Role[]; //this is what I use to populate the checkbox data with.

isUserRole: boolean = false;

// this is the object I want to populate from the form and send to the api to insert into the 
Db.
user: Member = {
userId: '',
userName: '',
emailAddress: '',
roles: [],
userAgencies: [],
processLevels: []
};

this.roleService.getAllroles().subscribe(response => {
  this.roles = response;
  this.user.roles = response;
  var role = this.roles.find(r => r.roleName == "User");
  if (role.roleName == "User") {
    this.isUserRole = true;
  }
}
);

    onRoleChange(roleId, roleName, $event) {
    if ($event.target.checked)
        this.user.roles.push(roleId);
    else {
        this.user.roles.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you're asking many questions and your problem isn't that clear. Please try to have more precise questions so we can help you !

Comment: I may have gave too much detail. Basically, I'm just trying to uncheck a checkbox (if checked) when I select a checkbox. I may have 4 roles. Admin, SuperAdmin, User, ProcessLevel. I check Admin, and Superadmin, then if I check ProcessLevel, I want to uncheck Admin and SuperAdmin

Answer (score 0):

You should think in variables and use [(ngModel)], not use change and checked

Imagine you has some like

```
<div *ngFor="let role of roles">
  <input #check type="checkbox" [ngModel]="user.roles && user.roles.indexOf(role.roleId)>-1"
    (ngModelChange)="change(role.roleId,check.checked)">{{role.roleName}}
</div>

  change(id: any, checked: boolean) {
    if (checked) {
      if (!this.user.roles) this.user.roles = [id];

      if (this.user.roles.indexOf(id) < 0) {
        this.user.roles = [...this.user.roles, id].sort((a, b) =>
          this.roles.findIndex(x => x.roleId == a) >
          this.roles.findIndex(x => x.roleId == b)
            ? 1
            : -1
        );
      }
    }
    if (!checked) {
      this.user.roles = this.user.roles.filter(x => x != id);
      if (!this.user.roles.length) this.user.roles = null;
    }
  }
```

Well, this makes that when check one checkbox, the variable user.roles add/remove the roleId

Now you want that is some is checked this.roles.users becomes null, so use a variable 'processLevel'  and change a few the function change

```
  change(id: any, checked: boolean) {
    if (checked) {
       ....
       this.processLevel=false; //<--add this line
    }
    ...
  }
```

And add a checkbox

```
<input type="checkBox" [ngModel]="processLevel" 
        (ngModelChange)="processLevel=$event;$event && user.roles=null">Process Level
```

See that in ngModelChange I use $event && [instructions], that's mean that if $event is true the instructions is executed

You can see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gbxjy2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)